# Does Bamboo plan support embedded shell command?

Tags: bamboo

From "https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/script-289277046.html", it gives me the meaning as follows:

```
You can use Bash on Linux, and batch files on Windows.
```

I know I can invoke the sh file in the "inline" format such as：

```
bash test.sh
```

So, my question is that:
Can i embedded the shell directly in its body like follows?

```
git add . || exitMsg
```

If the answer yes, how can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Thumb rule: If you can execute a command in a Terminal, you can execute in Bamboo as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly add whatever command you wanted to execute in a terminal. If you choose *inline* interpretor, you can as well add the contents of the bash script inside and it will be executed.

As you know, Bamboo expects `exit 0` for a successful execution. Anything else results in a failure.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to upvote my answer if you found it helpful :)

Comment: Yes, I have voted up, however my reputation is less than 15 which means the publicity cannot see my vote up.

Comment: Aha, I wasn't aware of that. Thanks anyway.